# screen command called from within a script, within a "su -c" command creates files on root directory

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu-screen, sh, su

I'm executing this script from user root in directory "/":

```
su -c "sh /home/bob/start_server.sh" bob
```

and "start_server.sh" contains

```
screen -d -m -S serverscreen mono startserver.exe
```

However all the files created by "startserver.exe" are created in the root directory "/", so it fails silently (I guess because of permission problems as it works if I cd to "/home/bob" before calling the "u -c" command line)

I checked the [manual](http://www.linfo.org/su.html) for the "su" command, but I didn't find any clues there.

Could it be that the "screen" resets the current directory and executes from "/" instead of "/home/bob"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mono but does this work?
screen -d -m -S serverscreen bash -c 'cd /home/bob; mono startserver.exe'

Comment: Yes this works, same as if I cd to the user directory in the script file. I'm trying to get it to work only with the one command however ;)